# The meaning of "to cut the biscuit"

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of this expression? Does it mean that something meets the expectations or it is up to standard?

Edit: Here is an example of usage.

http://www.edition38.com/forums/index.php?showtopic=150120&st=40

> that is one seriously pimp car! i have three old school favourites,
>   bmw e30, golf mk2 and the 190e and **this cuts the biscuit**! good work

Comment: Please add some context for the phrase.

Comment: @Matt Эллен I've added an example of a phrase where it's being used.

Comment: Wow, two biscuit questions within the span of a week. Crazy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"This cuts the biscuit" isn't a well-known phrase. I can only find two examples on [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22this+cuts+the+biscuit%21%22), one is quoted in the question and the other is:

> I understand it happening in earlier chappys but this cuts the biscuit but all suggestions aside this is the best yet.

There's nothing else in Google Books or Google Groups, so guessing from the context alone it sounds like it means something is above expectations.

---

It's probably a confusion of "[take the biscuit](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/take_the_biscuit)":

> (*idiomati, UK*) To be particularly bad, objectionable, or egregious.
> *I've seen bad grammar, but this takes the biscuit.*
> (*idiomatic, Canada*) To be of no further use; to be near death.
>
> **Synonyms**
> (*to be particularly egregious*): take the cake (*US*):
> (*to be of no further use*): have the biscuit (*Canada*):

And "[cut the mustard](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cut_mustard)":

> (*idiomatic*) To suffice; to be good or effective enough.
> *Give me the bigger hammer. This little one just doesn't **cut the mustard**.*
>
> **Usage notes**
> This idiom usually appears in negative polarity contexts: “doesn't cut the mustard”, “can't cut the mustard”, and so on.

---

The slang [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=let%27s%20cut%20this%20biscuit) defines *let's cut this biscuit* as:

> A phrase that is used used to signal, perhaps impatiently, a desire for something to begin. It could be a project, a trip, asking someone out--anything for which preparations have been made, and a specific goal is to be achieved.
>
> *1. "All right people, let's cut this biscuit!"*
>
> *2. A: "So you ready to hit the party? Jenna's going to be there, you know."*
>
> *B: "Yeah, man, let's cut this biscuit."*

However, it was defined in 2007 and is the only definition, with only 16 upvotes and 4 downvotes, showing it's not very common at all.

Answer (score 1):

I found this expression in a different context:

*As to how to grow that savings plan to the one-quarter million dollar level, this is a topic for another day. You probably already know that a 2% savings account is not going to **cut the biscuit**.*

Here, I understand it to mean **do the trick**, i.e. to succeed in solving a problem. I could also interpret it as **be suitable for a specific task or purpose.**

Comment: So, similar to *"cut the mustard"*.

Comment: Yes, I'd automatically assume the author had misremembered the phrase.

Answer (score -1):

I heard Gram Parsons say "alright let's cut this biscuit" on a record album, but I don't remember which album. I assumed he meant cutting a song on a record (biscuit).

Comment: This is clearly not the meaning of "cut the biscuit" that the asker requested. Also, please add an adequate source to your answer; mentioning the name of a music artist is not sufficient.